# How do I completely wipe out NIC settings with Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Have a smidge of a problem. I am trying to completely blank out the IP address, subnet mask, and default gateway of a single NIC on one of my VMs.

I open up IPv4 Properties on that NIC and set it to DHCP (there is no DHCP server available to it and it isn't getting a Windows APIPA address) and then I look in Advanced and make sure there aren't alternate addresses assigned. I close out all of the windows. Then, I open up CMD and type `ipconfig` and it shows that it has an IP address, subnet mask, and a default gateway. I even tried Disabling and Enabling the NIC and typing `Restart-NetAdapter -Name "Ethernet"` and there are no changes.

In PS, I type `Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -DisplayName "Network Address"` and it shows `--` under the DisplayValue.

For some reason, and I'm not sure why (I didn't give it the ol' College Try), but when I type `Set-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet" -IPAddress "0.0.0.0"` it shows red. I try putting in a valid address to see if maybe the cmdlet won't take all zeros and it does the same thing. I checked the `man` page and I'm fairly sure that the format is correct (I tried `$ip = @("0.0.0.0")` and gave it $ip and $ip[0] but it still, no joy).

I just want all of the NIC settings wiped and it seems like it is but `ipconfig` and `Get-NetIPAddress`, and `Get-NetIPConfiguration` keep showing addresses whereas `Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -DisplayName "Network Address"` show that it's blank.

Why won't it let me wipe the configs (without doing an OOBE SysPrep)? I feel like the answer is probably something simple that I'm just overlooking but I haven't really found anything online--it's mostly just ways to work with your NIC configurations within Powershell.

Could anyone help shine some light on what is actually going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have several NICs, `Get-NetAdapter` will list all adapters with their respective index, `Get-NetAdapter -ifIndex $ | Get-NetIPAddress | Remove-NetIPAddress` (substitute $ with desired adapter index) will wipe IP configuration.

In case of a vm with a single adapter you can omit the index:
`Get-NetAdapter | Get-NetIPAddress | Remove-NetIPAddress`

Comment: I was able to successfully remove the IP address and subnet mask with `Get-NetAdapter | Get-NetIPAddress | Remove-NetIPAddress -Confirm:$false` but it doesn't remove the default gateway.

Comment: It doesn't look like the machine is behaving. Did you happen to replace the vm NIC or copy this vm? I had such encounters when vm configuration was tampered somehow in such a way that it would introduce a new network device, leaving the old one as disconnected hidden device. This can be revealed via device manager and devices removed. If this happens to be the case, an few reboots and repeated ip configuration removal should get rid of this.

Comment: I remember seeing issues like that with VMware. I'm using Hyper-V (not my personal preference but it is what it is). I did pull up devmgmt.msc and checked Hidden Devices to see but there weren't any extra Network Adapters. I'm not sure but I think the VM was a copy of the Host (server) image and was SysPrep'd and captured with Acronis. I think I can work around it, though. 

Thank you for the help and the insight. It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49702587/1390548) shows how to remove IP and gateway

Answer (score 0):

> but it doesn't remove the default gateway.

Try this. ( it works only 4 IPv4 though. )

```
> Get-NetRoute -AddressFamily IPv4 | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.NextHop -ne "0.0.0.0"} | %{ Remove-NetRoute -NextHop $_.NextHop -Confirm:$false }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).